# Django Follow / Unfollow button does not change

Tags: django

I am trying to create a generic social media platform with django. The follow button works functionally, but doesn't text from "follow". The follower and following counts get updated appropriately. You can follow and unfollow people from the button. I just need the text to change.

Models.py:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following', related_query_name='follower')
    followed_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers', related_query_name='followed')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Views.py:

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': user})

    @login_required
    def follow(request, username):
        user_to_follow = get_object_or_404(User, 
    username=username)
    follow, created = 
    Follow.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, followed_user=user_to_follow)
        if not created:
            follow.delete()
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'home'))

def unfollow(request, username):
        user_to_unfollow = get_object_or_404(User, 
    username=username)
        try:
            follow = 
    Follow.objects.get(user=request.user, 
    followed_user=user_to_unfollow)
            follow.delete()
        except Follow.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'home'))
```

URLS.py:

```
    path('follow/<str:username>/', views.follow, name='follow'),
    path('unfollow/<str:username>/', views.unfollow, name='unfollow'),
```

Profile.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="profile">
    <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
    <p>Followers: {{ user.followers.count }}</p>
    <p>Following: {{ user.following.count }}</p>


        {% if request.user in user.followers.all %}
            <form method="post" action="{% url 
'unfollow' user.username %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button 
type="submit">Unfollow</button>
            </form>
        {% else %}
            <form method="post" action="{% url 
'follow' user.username %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button 
type="submit">Follow</button>
            </form>
        {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show us the view that renders profile.html.

Comment: added the profile view. Is that where I went wrong? Did I not load the appropriate stuff, and that's why my buttons aren't working?